# Rails has_many and belongs_to method relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to learn Rails has_many and belongs_to method to create collection of schedule.I read many information about this.And I can't understand `:dependent => :destroy` mean.

what does it works for?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-dependent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:dependent => :destroy
```

This tells rails to delete all the child instances when a parent instance is deleted.  Generally you want to do this if you don't want child instances hanging around when its parent has been deleted.

Comment: Please be careful when using word `deleted` vs `destroyed`. There is quite a huge difference in rails.

Answer (score 0):

`:dependent => :destroy` means when you delete the parent object it's children objects are automatically deteted.